# Hit a roadblock in the Rails Tutorial: "Could not find generator rspec:install."

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm working through the rails tutorial and am stuck at the point at which you use RSpec in place of Test::Unit.

Specifically, when I run:

```
$ rails generate rspec:install
```

I get:

```
Could not find generator rspec:install.
```

Here's what my Gemfile looks like:

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.1.0'
gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.4'

group :development do
  gem 'rspec-rails', "2.6.1"
end

group :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails', '2.6.1'
  gem 'webrat', '0.7.1'
end
```

Are my version numbers wrong or something? I've tried solutions that have been posted to similar questions here on stack overflow, but nothing's worked.

This seems like it should be an easy problem to fix, so it's especially annoying that I'm stuck. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just started the Rails tutorial today. I searched stackoverflow to see if anyone was having issues and came upon this question. I'm a total noob, but is it possible that you're having an issue because you're already running Rails 3.1? I know the tutorial doesn't cover updating to 3.1 until Chapter 13. Just a thought...

Comment: I uninstalled 3.1, then installed 3.0.9, and it seemed to work! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What version of bundler are you using? There was a bug with an earlier version of Bundler (about six months ago), where gems included in :development, :test, etc. weren't loaded properly.

Comment: 1.0.18, I think. Is that okay? What's the easiest way to check?

Answer (score 0):

try typing "bundle install" to make sure your rspec-rails is installed..  Then do your "rails generate rspec:install" command.